# xdg-open url as variable bash

Tags: linux, bash, browser

i'm trying to open a url to a website using xdg-open. Is it possible to open the url without specifying explicitly the website url but instead saving it inside a variable?

Desired result:

```
url = https://stackoverflow.com
...
xdb-open url
```

This brings up *No such file or directory*.

Explicitly stating the url works, but I was wondering if it could be done using the variable.
This works:

```
xdb-open https://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
url=https://stackoverflow.com
xdg-open $url
```

Comment: Probably a mistake on my part, but on linux mint this brings up: ./test.sh: line 1: url: command not found.

Comment: No, that's my mistake. There shouldn't be spaces around '='.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the answer, if you edit it i can save it for others who might be making the same mistake